# list to incrementing dict system (should be simple)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, arraylist, valueerror

I am trying to create a system where I convert a list into a dictionary. The keys should be items from the list while the values for each **unique** key should be an incrementing number (1,2,3,4, etc.).

Desired outcome:

```
Input:
list = ["Ford", "Ford", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda"]

Output:
dict = {
  "Ford": 1,
  "Ford": 1,
  "Chevy": 2,
  "Chevy": 2,
  "Chevy": 2,
  "Honda": 3,
  "Honda": 3,
  "Honda": 3,
  "Honda": 3,
}
```

I tried using this as it would allow me to start from 0 and increment. It didn't end up working.

```
dict = {}
list = []
for x, index in list:
  if x not in list:
      dict[x] = len(dict)
```

This is the error I got:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can’t have duplicate keys in a dict; your desired output t isn't possible.

Comment: Several problems: 1. You should use `enumerate` to iterate over a list while indexing, and then the order is `index, element` 2. You are iterating over `list` (which is a bad variable name BTW) and then the `if` checks if that element is **not** in the list. This check does not make sense. 3. You can't have duplicate keys in a dict

Comment: @MarkMeyer is there anyway to have one key and multiple values for that key

Comment: @MarkMeyer i think I would like one key and then a list of values

Comment: @MarkMeyer can you help me with that

Comment: @DeepSpace check out my above comments

Comment: @DeepSpace can you leave an edit with the above suggestions. would appreciate it. im stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sorted list (as you do in the example) you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) `groupby()` and `count()` to nicely do this. `count()` creates an incrementing iterator that increases evey time you use it. When you zip that with the groups you can a single incrementing number for each group in your list.

```
from itertools import groupby, count

l = ["Ford", "Ford", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda"]

d = {}
for cnt, (k, v) in zip(count(1), groupby(l)):
    d[k] = [cnt] * len(list(v))
```

`d` will be:

```
{'Ford': [1, 1], 'Chevy': [2, 2, 2], 'Honda': [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

If this list is not sorted you can simply sort it first.

Comment: how would I sort it?

Comment: `sorted(l)` will return a copy of `l` in sorted order while leaving `l` untouched, `l.sort()` will modify `l` in place to sort it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the use case is for this, but personally I'm not sure I love the idea of using `[3, 3, 3, 3]` to represent "`Honda` has ID `3` and appears four times in the original list". If all we want to track is the number of times `Honda` shows up, we might as well just store the number instead of storing a list of that many elements. So something like `'Honda': (3, 4)` or even `'Honda': {'ID': 3, 'count': 4}` for readability.

Comment: Fair enough @NathanPierson, I was just answering the question as asked in the comments. I have no idea what the intended use case is. Hopefully it's clear that `len(list(v))` gives the count of items and `cnt` is the group index. And thanks for adding the `sort()` clarification.

Comment: Oh, certainly. Just presenting some designs for @Juliette to consider, really. Your code is pretty straightforward to modify to produce different representations of the underlying gathered information.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that you cant have duplicated keys in the dict.

Use a combination of `set` with `enumerate` and a dict comprehension.

```py
{v:i for i,v in enumerate(set(l))}
```

Example result:

`{'Honda': 0, 'Chevy': 1, 'Ford': 2}`

And please, do not use `dict` or `list` as variable names since you are shadowing the `dict` and `list` built-in functions.

Comment: @DeepSpace, my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Netwave this doesnt allow me to handle multiple instances of Honda or Chevy

Comment: maybe something like Honda: [0,0,0}, Chevy: [1,1,1] would be bettetr

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable instead of len(dict) and check if dictionary already has key or not accordingly add key,value pair

```
dict={}
list=["Ford", "Ford", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda"]
count=1
for i in list:
    if i in dict:
        continue
    dict[i]=count
    count+=1
print(dict)
```

Comment: Check out my comments on the original post and i would like if you could edit it

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError you're getting is because `for x, index in list:` is invalid. A list's iterator will only return a single object, the value in the list. If you want to get both the index of the element and the element, you need `enumerate`. However, it's not necessarily the best way to get an index to use for the car's name. Also, following DeepSpace's and Netwave's suggestion, I'm using variable names that aren't also Python keywords.

```
cars_list = ["Ford", "Ford", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda", "Honda"]
cars_dict = {}
for car_name in cars_list:
    cars_dict.setdefault(car_name, len(cars_dict))
```

`setdefault` will set the value of `cars_dict[car_name]` if `car_name` isn't already present as a key, but won't change the value if `car_name` is already present. `len(cars_dict)` will be the number of keys, so when you do add a new car, it will be a value that hasn't previously been used.

This still won't produce a dictionary with duplicate keys, but:

```
print(cars_dict)
# yields {'Ford': 0, 'Chevy': 1, 'Honda': 2}
```

Comment: this doesnt allow me to handle multiple instances of Honda or Chevy

Comment: maybe something like Honda: [0,0,0}, Chevy: [1,1,1] would be better?